# Python 2.7 List of Lists Manipulation

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7

I am new to Python 2.7. Below is a subset of my data, which is just a list of lists, and would like to sum the values of the lists with both the same type (`myList[0]`) and same dates (`myList[8]`) into a new single list.

```
myList = [
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 123123, 123, 456456, 456, '1/8/2014'],
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 321321, 321, 654654, 654, '1/8/2014'],
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 987987, 987, 789789, 789, '1/9/2014'],
    [u'Notional', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 320320, 320, 210210, 210, '1/13/2014'],
    [u'Notional', u'Completeness Check', u'Break', 121121, 121, 412412, 412, '1/13/2014']
]
```

I am trying to get the result below but do not know how to do so:

```
newList = [
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 444444, 444, 1111110, 1110, '1/8/2014'],
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 987987, 987, 789789, 789, '1/9/2014'],
    [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 320320, 320, 210210, 210, '1/13/2014'],
    [u'Notional', u'Consistency Check:Completeness Check', u'Break', 441441, 441, 622622, 622, '1/13/2014']
]
```

In the new list of lists (`newList`), the lists with the same dates of the same type were combined into a single list but with with their numerical values summed and the description item (`myList[1]`) values concatenated with a `":"`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have an idea: `itertools.groupby()` (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @newtover: That's not that efficient when the data isn't yet sorted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what I wouldn't give for an optimized function of `groupby` that worked on unsorted lists.

Comment: @AdamSmith: It's called a dictionary... :-P

Comment: Your output sample doesn't match your actual input. There is no `'MtM', '1/13/2014'` pair, for example.

Comment: i would strongly recommend looking into `pandas`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map entries to a common sum:

```
sums = {}
for entry in myList:
    key = entry[0], entry[-1]
    if key not in sums:
        sums[key] = entry[:]
        sums[key][1] = set([entry[1]])
    else:
        sums[key][3:-1] = [s + elem for s, elem in zip(sums[key][3:-1], entry[3:-1])]
        sums[key][1].add(entry[1])

newList = [e[:1] + [':'.join(e[1])] + e[2:] for e in sums.values()]
```

1. The items are grouped on the first and last elements.
2. All but the first 3 and the last column are summed.
3. Output order can be arbitrary.
4. The 3rd column (`u'Break'`) doesn't vary.

Demo:

```
>>> myList = [
...     [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 123123, 123, 456456, 456, '1/8/2014'],
...     [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 321321, 321, 654654, 654, '1/8/2014'],
...     [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 987987, 987, 789789, 789, '1/9/2014'],
...     [u'Notional', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 320320, 320, 210210, 210, '1/13/2014'],
...     [u'Notional', u'Completeness Check', u'Break', 121121, 121, 412412, 412, '1/13/2014']
... ]
>>> sums = {}
>>> for entry in myList:
...     key = entry[0], entry[-1]
...     if key not in sums:
...         sums[key] = entry[:]
...         sums[key][1] = set([entry[1]])
...     else:
...         sums[key][3:-1] = [s + elem for s, elem in zip(sums[key][3:-1], entry[3:-1])]
...         sums[key][1].add(entry[1])
... 
>>> [e[:1] + [':'.join(e[1])] + e[2:] for e in sums.values()]
[[u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 987987, 987, 789789, 789, '1/9/2014'],
 [u'Notional', u'Completeness Check:Consistency Check', u'Break', 441441, 441, 622622, 622, '1/13/2014'],
 [u'MtM', u'Consistency Check', u'Break', 444444, 444, 1111110, 1110, '1/8/2014']]
```

Comment: What if myList have a unknown entries length?

Comment: @felipsmartins: This'll take any finite length `myList` as input; the *last* element is assumed to be the date, the first 3 elements are not summed.

Comment: @felipsmartins: if your lengths vary throughout your data sequence, you'd need to use `itertools.izip_longest()` with a fill-value of `0` instead of plain `zip()`; the way the slice assignment works, that'll dynamically grow the summed entries in `sums`.

Comment: @felipsmartins: and apologies, the previous iteration was summing the first entry twice. Fixed now.

Comment: How exactly would the code change if myList has an unknown length? After replacing zip() with itertools.izip.longest(), is just the parameter value "fillvalue=0" all that needs to be changed? Thank you!

Comment: When I ran the code on lists of random lengths I noticed that some of them have duplicates results for the same date. I am thinking I just did not modify the code properly to deal with variable lengths. Thank you!

Comment: It is resolved, I am trying to extend it to a variable length array but I think it is my modification of your code that is the problem.